# Reidrect to another page from a form

Tags: html, forms, redirect, iframe

i have two pages (Example1.html and Example2.html) On Example1.html i have a form that the users submit an URL of a video and in Example2 an iframe that load the Example1 users submitted URL, this is the iframe:

```
  <iframe style="width: 320px; height: 100px; border: 0px none;" src="http://embed.yt-mp3.com/es/watch?v=HEREISTHEURLOFTHEFORM"></iframe>
```

So if anyone can help me to introduce on the iframe of Example2.html the form submit of the users in Example1.html

Answer (score 0):

In HTML forms you can easily proceed information by posting them to a PHP file! You can use POST or GET method to pass a parameter.

Here's a nice tutorial/example how to achieve that. [Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)